# Finding local extremum in vector of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I need to find peaks of the vector of numbers. Do you know C++/C library where I can find function like that? Or could you recommend me some known function?

I need find local maximums (peaks). Not only a max value of the vector.

Comment: The first search result for `C++ vector min max` gave a pretty good  result.

Comment: I mean PEAKS (S at the end). I wrote about local maximums. Yes. Max value of the vector is a local maximum (it's a peak). I need find more peaks.

Comment: How do you define peaks?  Is it as simple as `(v[n] > v[n-1]) && (v[n] > v[n+1])`?

Comment: Voted to reopen - peaks are not (necessarily) the same as min/max, rather it is about local maxima/minima

Comment: I agree with @the_mandrill. The referenced answer solves the absolute maximum and minimum problem, not the local extrema problem.